# How do I format disk from UEFI shell?

Tags: hard-drive, shell, uefi, format, volume-label

I need to format 2 disks from pre-built UEFI shell.
So I have 2 questions.

1. How do I format a disk from UEFI Shell?
2. How do I know what is the disk name or label?

By the way, in the first question I want to know the command.

Comment: EFI Shell is not intended for partition management. Use a USB-bootable linux distro to do this.

Comment: @SamForbis, that would be good as an answer, perhaps adding a reference to a bootable USB, such as a Linux distro or rescue "disk".

Comment: @SamForbis.  Strange, I have being doing partition management from an EFI/UEFI Shell for nearly 20 years.  A numbers of vendors supply such utilities including Intel.  See https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/download/uefi-shell-disk-utilities-v13.html for example.